# $E(X^3)$ in terms of a generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, expected-value

If we suppose that $G(s)$ is the generating function of the random variable $X$ and that the variable $X$ takes nonnegative integer values only, then is there a good way of expressing $E(X^3)$ in terms of the function $G$? I've been trying to figure this out, but I'm not quite familiar with generating functions yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual generating function set-up, if $G(s)$ is the GF for $X$ then
$$G^{(k)}(1)=E(X(X-1)(X-2)\cdots(X-k+1)).$$
where $G^{(k)}$ is the $k$-th derivative of $G$.
Then
$$G'(1)=E(X),$$
$$G''(1)=E(X(X-1))=E(X^2)-E(X),$$
$$G'''(1)=E(X(X-1)(X-2))=E(X^3)-3E(X^2)+2E(X),$$
etc.
Therefore
$$E(X^3)=G'''(1)+3G''(1)+G'(1).$$

If you continue this for higher moments of $X$, the coefficients you get will be
[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 1):

I share @AnginaSeng's assumption that the generating function intended with the notation $G(s)$ is a [PGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function). But on the off chance we're both wrong:

- If $G$ is the [MGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), $E(X^3)=G^{(3)}(0)$;
- [if $G$ is the CGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_and_moments), $E[X^3]=G^{(3)}(0)+3G^\prime(0)G^{\prime\prime}(0)+[G^\prime(0)]^3$ (assuming we define the CGF as the log-MGF rather than the log-[CF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), which would put some powers of $i$ in there).